# How do I paste destination format in VBA, using PasteSpecial and Size?

Tags: excel, vba, trim, paste

I want to cltr + v and execute a code that pastes as best as possible my destination formatting

Well, I paste special the values and then reformat the values

But I have an error which occurs on the ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) line, "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed 1004 run-time error"

I want to make this code neat but I am having some trouble.

Also, for some reason (though the trim, right alignment, and name "calibri" work fine), the .Size of the pasted values don't ("object does not support this property" error)

Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
Sub PasteWithDestinationFormatting()

     ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

End Sub


Sub TrimAndFit()

    Dim r As Range


    Call PasteWithDestinationFormatting



    With Application.WorksheetFunction

        For Each r In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

            r.Value = .Trim(r.Value)

            r.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignRight

            r.Name = "Calibri"

            r.Size = 11

        Next r

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA intellisense should tip you off here. If you begin typing the offending line in the VBE, you'll see that `Size` is **not** an available property of a [`Range` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) (link to dox).

[image]

Assuming you want to set the font size to 11, you need:

```
r.Font.Size = 11
```

Comment: Thank you! How about the error when pasting special values, ...I copy from source format that i don't want to carry over to my destination, any thoughts good sir?

Comment: take off the `()` from `xlPasteValues`

Comment: Instead `ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)` try `ActiveCell.PasteSpecial paste:= XlPasteValues`

Comment: unable to reproduce that problem and tbh didn't know that's what you need help with (you should try to avoid asking two or more distinct questions!). That syntax should work. it's exactly correct barring some typo or transposition error.

Comment: Have you got anything in the clipboard? I don't see any call to range `.Copy`. it seems likely you don't have anything in your clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Copy value & formatting from cell A1 to A2
        .Range("A1").Copy .Range("A2")
    End With

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]